# Calculating Distance, converting to km and then cutting out decimal places

Tags: ios, swift

Edit 3:  Thank you beyowulf, I implemented your line of code and this is the [result!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAnRs.png) Exactly what I was hoping for.  Thank you for all the suggestions.

Edit 2:  Interesting, as per user27388882 suggestion I changed my code to:

```
//convert to kilometers
let kilometers = Double(round(traveledDistance) / 1000)
```

The result is three decimal places. Ideally I would like only two at most, but this is a step in the right direction! Thank you!

Edit 1: for clarification of "does not work": I guess I can't post a picture, but here is a link when viewed in the simulator. [The distance still appears as a super long string of decimals, despite using code to try and shorten the number of decimal places. What I perceive to not be working in my code is where the decimal places should be cut off.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOixe.png)

I am essentially creating an app that tracks a users location while riding their bicycle.  One feature is to take the distance travelled by the user and display it in KM.  I have gotten the distance function to work by searching through other posts.  I have also looked at NSNumberFormatter help documents, but implementing code I have seen does not work.  Is this an issue of distance being a double which is calculated from CLLocation? Another piece of potentially relevant information is that I am working in Xcode 7.2 and Swift2.

I don't want to post my whole code since I want to highlight where I am stuck, but not sure if more of my code is needed to solve this.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

// Global variables

var startLocation:CLLocation!
var lastLocation: CLLocation!
var traveledDistance:Double = 0


// Identify Labels
@IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!

// Create a location manager
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

//Calculate the distance between points as a total distance traveled...
if startLocation == nil {
    startLocation = locations.first! as CLLocation
} else {
    let lastLocation = locations.last! as CLLocation
    let distance = startLocation.distanceFromLocation(lastLocation)
    startLocation = lastLocation
    traveledDistance += distance

    //convert to kilometers
    let kilometers = traveledDistance / 1000


    //Convert to only two decimal places
    let nf = NSNumberFormatter()
    nf.minimumSignificantDigits = 1
    nf.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    nf.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle

    nf.stringFromNumber(kilometers)

    //Update the distance label
    self.distanceLabel.text = "\(kilometers) kilometers"
```

Help me, stackOverFlow. You're my only hope.

tl;dr round out decimal places from distance value calculated from user location using swift2.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean in this case? If we have to guess what the problem is it becomes very difficult to provide a useful answer. What result did you expect and what did you observe happen instead?

Comment: What is your actual problem with the posted code? Simply stating "does not work" isn't helpful at all. In what way exactly (be very clear and specific) doesn't it work? What results do you get? What results do you want exactly?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I just edited the post to show what I see in the simulator. The decimal places are super long and I would like it to be shorted to something along the lines of 0.02 kilometers.

Comment: Double(round(1000*kilometers)/1000) ?

Comment: Hi user2738882, I did a slight modification and your comment is a step in the right direction. Thank you! I left out the first "1000*" because it made the first movement as 24.735 kilometers.

Comment: @Nikolai check this apple extensions for converting meters to kilometres https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you for the resource on conversion of units, I was wondering if there was some documentation on that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't wait to round until you are ready to display the results? You can say something like:

```
let formatedString = String(format:"%.2f",Float(traveledDistance / 1000.0 + .005))
```

To get traveledDistance rounded to the neared hundredth of a kilometer.

Comment: This worked, I don't have enough reputation points to upvote your answer, but I wanted to let you know this line of code fixed the issue of too many decimal places.  Thank you!